# Print firebase data from arduino to 7 segment display

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, stm32f0

I am trying to get my firebase data and display it to my 7-segment using Arduino and I am getting the help of a python script to send data to the serial monitor. While it detects the `Serial.available()` inside the loop but I don't know how could I get that particular value and display its first digit to my 7-segment

***Currently for the test I am just trying to display 1 if there is data matches inside serial monitor and arduino***

Adruino:

```
#define A PA0
#define B PA1
#define C PA2
#define D PA3
#define E PA4
#define F PA5
#define G PA6
int a = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(E, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()){
     //  Serial.println("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
//  sevenSeg(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0); //   0
//  delay(500);

  if(Serial.readString() == Serial.readString()){
    sevenSeg(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0); //  1
    delay(500);
  }

  }else{
  sevenSeg(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
  }//   0 



}


void sevenSeg (int g, int f, int e, int d, int c, int b, int a)
{
  digitalWrite(A, a);
  digitalWrite(B, b);
  digitalWrite(C, c);
  digitalWrite(D, d);
  digitalWrite(E, e);
  digitalWrite(F, f);
  digitalWrite(G, g);

}
```

Python Script:

```
import pyrebase
import argparse
import datetime
import time
import math
import serial
from serial import Serial

time_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%b%d_%I:%M:%S%p").upper()

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-t", "--temp", help="Patient temperature at time of reading") #
ap.add_argument("-r", "--heart", help="Patient heart rate at the time of reading")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


#firebase configuration
firebaseConfig = {
    "apiKey": "",
    "authDomain": "heartrate-firebase.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://heartrate-firebase-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",
    "projectId": "heartrate-firebase",
    "storageBucket": "heartrate-firebase.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "851991577466",
    "appId": "1:851991577466:web:daaf323d9af64fd3318cc3",
}


firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
db = firebase.database()

if args.get("temp", None) is not None:
    data = {"Temperature": args.get("temp", None)}
    db.child("Temperature").child(time_str).set(data)

if args.get("heart", None) is not None:
    data = {"HeartRate": args.get("heart", None)}
    db.child("HeartRate").child(time_str).set(data)

user = db.child("HeartRate").get()

for x in user.each():
    date = db.child("HeartRate").child(x.key()).child("HeartRate").get()
    print("Heart Rate: " + date.val())


userTemp = db.child("Temperature").get()
for x in userTemp.each():
    date = db.child("Temperature").child(x.key()).child("Temperature").get()
    # date = db.child("Temperature").get()
    print("Temperature: " + date.val())
    

with serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=5) as ser:
    time.sleep(2)
    ser.write((date.val() + '\n').encode())
    time.sleep(1)
    y = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    print(y)
    # ser.close()
```

All I end up with is displaying 0. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Serial.readString() == Serial.readString()` will never be true. do you try to solve a problem with the seven segment or a Serial communication problem?

Comment: Well, I have also tried doing `Serial.readString() == a` in This case `a="2"` and I do have `String 2` inside my database still it doesn't matches.

Comment: I guess Serial Monitor sends "2\n" or "2\r\n" depending on your line end setting in Serial Monitor.

Comment: Yes its sending "2\r\n" but I am still not getting the number "2" on my seven-segment display. **Any Ideas how I can do that**

Comment: because "2\r\n" is not equal to "2"? and you print 0 or 1?

Comment: Ok I am trying this in my void loop 
`if(Serial.available()){ 
char inString = Serial.read();
if(inString == a){
      sevenSeg(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1); // 2
      delay(500);    
  }else{
  sevenSeg(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
  }` and I have `String a = "2\r\n"` Still its not working.

Comment: `inChar` is '2' and `a` is 2. ASCII code of '2' is 50 so 50 is not equal to 2

Comment: Well, thanks but I find the problem it's because `\r\n`. So can you guide me on how I can remove that "\r\n"?

Comment: with String.trim() https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/trim/

Comment: Hey thanks it works!!!

Comment: @Juraj I have posted another question can you help me with that too. The link of that question  is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809954/convert-byte-array-to-string-and-than-match-it-with-string-in-arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I was receiving `2\r\n` from the database so to remove \r\n I used `strip()` to remove \r\n and it worked.