# Convert Byte array to string and than match it with string in arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I cannot able to match my serial monitor data to my string.
The way I am sending data to serial is `data.getBytes()` where data is a string and I have to keep it that way.

So now I have to convert that data to string and than match it to its equivalent string but I couldn't figure that out.

aduino code inside void loop() is:

```
 if(Serial.available()){ // only send data back if data has been sent
    byte msg = Serial.read();
    byte plain[a.length()]; // String a = "2"
    byte inString = a.getBytes(plain, a.length(), 0); // read the incoming data
    if(inString == msg){
      sevenSeg(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1); // 2
      delay(500);
    
  }else{
    sevenSeg(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0); //  1
      delay(500);
  }
else{
sevenSeg(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0); //0
}
```

All I end up with is displaying 1. Even though I am sending data to the serial monitor. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is actually in `msg` when you check it? For example might it have a newline or something else that's upsetting things?

Comment: `msg` is just a new byte. I am declaring it first time over there.

Comment: Yes, I wondered what actual value it had. Of course if it's a single byte then a newline can't be the problem. Daft question, but you are actually receiving a byte containing decimal 50, aren't you? Not a byte containing decimal 2?

Comment: so I am receiving `[50]` in my serial monitor and I am not sure how to equate that with my `msg`

Comment: Is [50] what is coming in to `msg`? If so, then that should match as 50 is the ASCII value of the string "2".